# What is the maximum size of the redux store in a react native application?

Tags: react-native, performance, redux, mobile-application

I am writing a React Native App. I am using Redux to store my data. I am using this data everywhere hence I store it in redux and don't request it from server. This data is modified with combined of 3-5 reducers and 40-60 actions.

In my case the data can be about 1-2 MB.

does this affect my App performance?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more details: Probably not. Even rendering a single button will probably take up more CPU time and you will have to store a lot of data before you will start filling any relevant amount of RAM or even reaching the size of a single image.

Comment: Hi @phry , In my case the data can be about 1-2 MB, I'll update the question as well.

Comment: A modern phone has gigabytes of RAM. No need to sweat about 1-2MB.

Comment: ok thanks, so this means it wont affect the overall performance (process, not get stuck) of the app right ?

Comment: As long as you are not targeting devices older than 10 years, it's very doubtful to have any impact.